# Does MongoEngine cache the same reference on different objects?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Suppose I have this model:

```
class B(db.Document):
    pass

class A(db.Document):
    b = db.ReferenceField(B)
```

I know that if I have a `A` object, then calling `a.b` on it multiple times will only query MongoDB once, because of caching by MongoEngine.

However, if I have a list of **n** `A` objects, each one of them referencing the **same** `B` object, if I call `a.b` on each of them will this query MongoDB once or **n** times?

Answer (score 2):

Mongoengine derefernces on a per-document basis so you will query the `b` collection **n times** - given this code:

```
import mongoengine as mdb
class B(mdb.Document):
    pass

class A(mdb.Document):
    n = mdb.IntField()
    b = mdb.ReferenceField(B)

b = B().save()

# Save 100 A docs
for n in range(100):
    A(n=n,b=b).save()

# Make a list of the A docs
a_objects = list([A.objects(n=_).get() for _ in range(100)])


for a in a_objects:
    print (a.n, a.b)
```

If you run this while looking at [mongostat](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) you can see that this results in 101 inserts and then 200 queries.

This is one reason *you should avoid making lists of mongoengine documents*, consider this code:

```
import mongoengine as mdb
class B(mdb.Document):
    pass

class A(mdb.Document):
    n = mdb.IntField()
    b = mdb.ReferenceField(B)

b = B().save()

# Save 100 A docs
for n in range(100):
    A(n=n,b=b).save()

# Use a QuerySet on A
for a in A.objects:
    print (a.n, a.b)
```

This will result in 101 inserts and 101 queries because all the A documents you need will be returned in a singe query (provided the number of documents is within the default limit).